# How to use css to style xhtml markup made only of divs like a table

Tags: css, xhtml, tablelayout

See source code of this http://jsbin.com/iveso I can't change anything in xhtml code.

And i need cross browser output exact like this.
[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/445/5025516010.jpg](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/445/5025516010.jpg)

How we can give same look with less and optimize css

This is CSS

```
#ConferencesContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#ConferencesContainer img {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#ConferencesContainer #ConferencesItemsContainer img {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#ConferencesHeaderContainer {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#ConferencesTitleHeaderContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

#ConferencesPDFHeaderContainer {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

#ConferencesExternalLinkHeaderContainer {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

#ConferencesHtmlHeaderContainer {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

.Conferencesnorth-america-2009ItemContainer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #008999;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.Conferencesaustralia-and-asia-2008ItemContainer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #008999;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.Conferencesinvestor-conference-2008ItemContainer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #008999;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#ConferencesContainer .ConferencesTitleContainer {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px 0;
  width: 40%;
}

#ConferencesContainer .ConferencesPdfContainer {
  float: left;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

#ConferencesContainer .ConferencesExtLinkContainer {
  float: left;
  left: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

#ConferencesContainer .ConferencesHtmlContainer {
  float: left;
  left: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

#ConferencesAcrobatWarningContainer {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.Conferencesaustralia-and-asia-2008ItemContainer #ConferencesasiaTitleContainer {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Conferencesaustralia-and-asia-2008ItemContainer #ConferencesaustraliaTitleContainer {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Edit:**

**I found links which are useful for me**

1. http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di
2. http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/table-in-css.html

Comment: I would think someone with 1.8K reputation would know that they should post some code for questions like this...

Comment: The answer is simple.  Just enter the question "How to make table like look with such type of code with help of css" into Stackoverflow.com and wait for the result to come out.  Do NOT read a book on basic CSS.  DO NOT attempt to understand the concepts.

Comment: "less and optimize css" --- less and more optimized than whose css? Theirs? Yours? Where is yours?

Comment: @Guffa, @Andrew Song, @Gregory Pakosz - I added my code i know it can be better and I just wanted to know how other people will code

Comment: @Jitendra > good! I found those links too :) see my edited answer for a starting point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day, teach him to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime"

Ok here we go. If started by installing [Firefox](http://getfirefox.com/) so that I can use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension.

So you apparently have no control over the the markup which is only made of `divs`. So far so good.

I changed a fragment of your css by removing `#ConferencesContainer` as Firebug obviously shows you that there is no `div` with the id `ConferencesContainer` in your markup anyway... Which explains why `#ConferencesContainer .ConferencesTitleContainer {` and alike select nothing.

Then I removed the absolute positioning because as far as I can recall, this is something that doesn't play nice with IE. By the way, having `float: left` is useless if you then use `position: absolute`

To accommodate the fact that sometimes there is no pdf download link (hence no `div` in the markup), I made agenda item and pdf link divs float to the left. And I made biography and webcast divs `float` to the right and tricked the margins to switch the divs back to their intended position. Tricking the margins was necessary as the webcast div comes first in the markup (in respect to the biography div).

Of course, if you apply the stylesheet I'm giving you to a slightly different markup with "holes", that is to say missing divs because there is no corresponding link to output then it might not work.

In any case, I believe you now have enough to experiment with on your own, good luck.

```
.ConferencesTitleContainer {
float:left;
padding:2px 0;
width:40%;
background: red;
}
.ConferencesPdfContainer {
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:20%;
background: yellow;
}
.ConferencesExtLinkContainer {
float:right;
margin-left: -20%;
margin-right: 20%;
text-align:center;
width:20%;
background: lime;
}
.ConferencesHtmlContainer {
float: right;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: -20%;
text-align:center;
width:20%;
background: pink;
}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [pakosz.fr](http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/homework.png))</sub>

[See it in action.](http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/homework.html)

And, you might want to read [Top 10 CSS Table Designs](https://google.com/search/?q=css+table+design) or [10 CSS Table Examples](http://designshack.co.uk/articles/10-css-table-examples) for pretty styling.

PS: the coder colors are here to help visualizing divs.

Comment: @Gregory Pakosz code is not table based

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach him to fish, and he will sit in his boat and drink beer all day.

Comment: my question is not how to style <table> in css? ur links are good but has different purpose

Comment: I added ur css here http://jsbin.com/uximi3 and trying to correct formatting which is  not correct

Answer (score 3):

I think, you have to play with a bit . Furthermore, you definitely need some images and a lot of patience with the xhtml code and especially the great id & class names.

Here is something that can get you started:

```
.ConferencesTitleContainer, .ConferencesPdfContainer, .ConferencesExtLinkContainer, .ConferencesHtmlContainer, .ConferencesTitleHeaderContainer, .ConferencesPDFHeaderContainer, .ConferencesExternalLinkHeaderContainer, .ConferencesHtmlHeaderContainer {
float:left;
width:24%;
border-bottom:1px solid;
}
#ConferencesasiaTitleContainer, #ConferencesaustraliaTitleContainer {
width:96%;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: @Rossen Zahariev - thanks for your answer but how i will align icons in center?